# XML from webservice to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a web service task that saves the XML output to a variable.

The question now is what would the variable type be? Also how can I then transfer the XML variable to the SQL Server database? I can't seem to make the data flow work, XML source to ole db source? Am I on the right path? thanks

```
        <xs:element name="Table">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FlightDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="FlightNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

i need to save flight date and flight no to a temporary table in sql. it must have its own column like flightdate and flight no

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change XML Source Data Acces Mode to XML Data From Variable,

Then you can give "User::FlightInfoXML" Variable.

Comment: Then where you exactly struck ?

Comment: added new ss, how can i then map the columns of xml?  where do i go from here? do I have to create xsd file?

Comment: Yes, You have to create XSD.
Easily you can generate it,By Clicking on "Generate XSD" Button.
Just you have to specify path where you want to keep that XSD File on disk.

Comment: tried hitting the generate button it says that variable flightinfoxml does not contain xml

Comment: Ok, If Do you have that XML File on Disk for now.
Then Specify that XML path in XML Source by keeping Data Access mode XML File Location.
Then generate XSD.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28421/discussion-between-ram-bi-and-anonymous1110)

Comment: hi, i encountered a new problem,my xml source output returns no output at all, but i can map the columns etc.

Comment: Is it giving any warnings ? Or By keeping break point on dataflow task, once check web services output variable value.

Comment: it doesnt. i also added a data viewer, it doesnt return anything. =) can i send it to you via email?

Comment: I am saying that Keep break point(PreExecute) on Dataflow task or Keep (Post Execute break point) on Web services Task. And check Web Services Output Variable("User::FlightInfoXML") value. Just to check you getting data from web services or not.